# Comprehensive software testing timeline

Tags: test-design

Can someone explain clearly timeline for different types of testing.
Where does Integration, Load, Stress testing and acceptance testing fit in?
when are test plan for each of them is prepared (and what these test plans are based on eg. design, analysis, requirements)?
**It would be helpful to know where different types(performance, usability, regression etcetra) fit into levels(Integration, system, acceptance).**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each and every testing timeline is based on requirements , design and development size.It depends on project size, complexity etc. Also remember that not every project require all type of testing. So as a tester first of all it should be clear that which type of testing we will do for this particular project.

Test plan is always first step , So once requirement fixed you can start to create test plan. Testing can be start once design/development gets ready but you can create test plan once requirement fixed.

Test plan can contain following things as per "Standard for Software Test Documentation’
(IEEE 829) :

> 1 - Introduction
>
> 2 - Objective & Tasks
>
> 3 - Scope
>
> 4 - Testing Strategy
>
> 5 - Hardware Requirements
>
> 6 - Environment Requirements
>
> 7 - Test Schedule
>
> 8 - Features to Be Tested
>
> 9 - Features Not to Be Tested
>
> 10 - Resources/Roles & Responsibilities
>
> 11 - Dependencies
>
> 12 - Risks/Assumptions
>
> 13 - Tools
>
> 14 - Approvals
>
> 15 - References

Each and every step should have very detail description.

Regression testing can be done only when software is modified OR any new function added to software.

System testing is testing of whole system , If you do system testing then no need to do regression testing because you are checking everything so regression automation will be done here.

Acceptance testing can be done once all development completes , It is just comparison between your developed software and given requirement document to get confidence about level of quality.

Usability mostly done at last to ensure that how easy system is to use.It can be done by end user also.

Performance testing can be done if you require. You can do this to just know that how capable your system is if load comes on it. For ex: what will happen if my website will have traffic of 10K users in 2 hour. Mostly it can be done for large websites where possibilities of traffic is high.

All I have provided above based on your given details in question. You have not describe that what type of system you are going to test so I provided answer as per my experience and on general base.

Comment: Can you please let me know when are performance & stress testing done? I believe the flow will be UnitTesting --> Integraton Testing --> Acceptance testing. Where in here can we fit them?

Comment: As I told in answer , you can do performance testing to put load on website and to get its strength.  Stress testing you can do to estimate website capacity of load. Aim of stress testing it to break system/site by heavy load.                  For Ex : if you are going to live bug e-commerce site then you must to load / stress testing.

Comment: Also, when do we start preparing the test scenarios for stress, Load testing? and when do we start performing them?

Comment: test scenarios for stress and load you can do at last , once you complete all testing. Just before release , you should do stress/load testing.

Comment: Sorry, I should have asked how earliest can we start writing scenarios for Stress&Load Testing? For example, we can start writing Integration Test scenarios once we know requirements and execute once coding is done. Similarly when can we start writing and executing for Load and performance.

Comment: you can start write once requirement fixed.

Comment: and for performing the tests, when is the earliest we can start?

Comment: To perform it you should do it at last only. Once acceptance testing done. Because if any other type of bugs are in system then there is not meaning to do load/stress testing. So first complete all other testings , make sure system works proper in normal environment then do load/stress testing.

Comment: And if you find horrible performance then you're in big trouble - do not wait until the last moment to do this, do it as soon as you can ( dependent on project and risk of course )